# Why does my js not display anything?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I was wondering why does my js script not working properly when I call from external file in html

here is my js code

```
<script>

var interval=2000;
function toJson(){
    document.writeln("json file");
}
function toCsv(){
    document.writeln("csv file");
}


function process(){
    toJson();
    tocsv();
}
process();
setInterval(process,interval);

function terminate(){

    var timer=setInterval(process,interval);
    clearInterval(timer);
}

</script>
```

and here is index.html

```
<html>
<title>Test Javascript</title>
<head><script language="javascript" src="js/myscript.js"></head>
<body>
<h1>Test</h1>
<fieldset>
<legend>test javascript form</legend>
<form>
<input type="submit" onclick="process()" value="process">
<input type="submit" onclick="terminate()" value="terminate">
</form>
</fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

when I run it, I don't know why does it not display anything

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: `<script>` and `</script>` do _not_ belong into an external JavaScript file.

Comment: It's usually a good idea to use a debugging tool, such as Chrome's Developer Tools (`CTRL + SHIFT + I`).

Comment: don't use `document.writeIn` or `document.write` after page loads....will wipe out the whole page!

Comment: Man theres tons of errors in this small script

Comment: got it, when i put internal it works, now i have another question, how do i call php script in `code`
function process(){ 
 perform php script here;
 catch variabel from form and send to php script
} `code`

Answer (score 0):

Your function name is: toCsv and you are calling tocsv();